# How to extract strings from a localizable.strings-formatted file in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am constructing a PHP web app where users can upload their strings files (consisting of keys and values) from their ios/mac apps. I need to be able to extract the strings from these files, but it seems my regex skills are beyond rusty.

For instance, a file that looks like this:

```
STRING1 = "hello";
"good = bye" = "good = bye";
NAME = "Your name is \"%@\"";
"semicolon;confusion" = "I love semicolons; I hate semicolons"; "forget new line" = "forgot new line!";
```

Should yield:

```
[0] = ["STRING1","\"hello\""]
[1] = ["\"good = bye\"","\"good = bye\""]
[2] = ["NAME","\"Your name is \"%@\"\""]
[3] = ["\"semicolon;confusion\"","\"I love semicolons; I hate semicolons\""]
[4] = ["\"forget new line\"","\"forgot new line!\""]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array();
$lines = file('filename.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line)
    while(preg_match('/^\\s*("(?:[^"]|\\\\")*"|[^"]\\w*)\\s*=\\s*("(?:[^"]|\\\\")*"|[^"]\\w*)\\s*;/', $line, $groups) == 1) {
        // $group[1] contains the name, $group[2] contains the value
        array_push($data, array($groups[1], $groups[2])); 
        $line = trim(substr($line, strlen($groups[0])));
    }
```

I've assumed the input lives in a file called `filename.txt` and used that to populate the array of lines `$lines`. It should be fairly easy to adapt the code to populate `$lines` another way if you need to.

If you use `var_dump($data)` at the bottom of this code, you get the following output for the input you gave above:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(7) "STRING1"
        [1]=> string(7) ""hello""
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(12) ""good = bye""
        [1]=> string(12) ""good = bye""
    }
    [2]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(4) "NAME"
        [1]=> string(21) ""Your name is "%@"""
    }
    [3]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(21) ""semicolon;confusion""
        [1]=> string(38) ""I love semicolons; I hate semicolons""
    }
    [4]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(17) ""forget new line""
        [1]=> string(18) ""forgot new line!""
    }
}
```

I believe this is the format of the data you're expecting.

Comment: Doesnt seem to working. I vardumped $lines before the loop and confirmed the file is being read correctly, but the preg_match doesnt seem to work. I put an echo before the array_push and it is never echoed.

Comment: That's very strange. It continues to work on my machine. May I ask what version of PHP you're using and how you're testing the code? It's working well on my machine and the code is simple, so I'm struggling to imagine why it's working on my side and not on yours.

Comment: Actually it works with the input I provided in the question, and not with my actual input. So its something unexpected with my real input file. Answer is still correct, thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks. If you can post the "real" input I'd be happy to have a quick look at it if that's useful.

Comment: It seems the only difference is the working file is UTF-8, and non-working is UTF-16. I need it to work with UTF-16 as that is the standard for localizable strings file. Any idea why it doesnt?

Comment: Ah. That would do it. Unfortunately, Unicode is very poorly integrated into the PHP standard library. (For example, consider [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37391).) Rather than trying to wrestle with getting PCREs to work predictably and reliably with multibyte strings, you'd probably be better off building a simple parser with [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) instead. Unfortunately, Unicode is one of the places where PHP is well behind other languages. I'm not a PHP expert, though, so you may want to seek out a "second opinion."

Answer (score 0):

The pairs if they look like in your example could be matched with an expression like:

```
(?x)
(?<key> \w++ | " (?: [^"\\]++ | \\ . )*+ " )
\s*+ = \s*+
(?<val> " (?: [^"\\]++ | \\ . )*+ " )
\s*+ ;
```

Change it accordingly if you want to allow different quote characters or unquoted values.

[Example](http://ideone.com/OzTb17):

```
$str = <<<'__EOS__'
STRING1 = "hello";
"good = bye" = "good = bye";
NAME = "Your name is \"%@\"";
"semicolon;confusion" = "I love semicolons; I hate semicolons"; "forget new line" = "forgot new line!";
__EOS__;

$re = <<<'__EOS__'
/
(?<key> \w++ | " (?: [^"\\]++ | \\ . )*+ " )
\s*+ = \s*+
(?<val> " (?: [^"\\]++ | \\ . )*+ " )
\s*+ ;
/x
__EOS__;

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Sorry, as I said I am not very familiar with regex. What would the PHP look like that utilizes this expression?

Comment: @user1023127 added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can preg_match_all:

```
$str = <<< EOF
STRING1 = "hello";
"good = bye" = "good1 = bye1";
NAME = "Your name is \"%@\"";
"semicolon;confusion" = "I love semicolons; I hate semicolons"; "forget new line" = "forgot new line!";
EOF;

if (preg_match_all('~(?<key>.+?)\s+=\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?<val>.+?)\s*(?<=");~', $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

Then use arrays `$key` and `$val` to get your values.

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/9SIikc